# How to get selective data from multiple json files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

Let suppose I have `5` `json` files in which data is stored. 
Now I have `5` different logins(different users), and for each different login, seperate json data should be loaded. So, how can I implement this?
can I implement this without `getJson()` ?? 
I want to store it as 5 different js files with data as variables in it.
Any ideas?

I mean, I want to get variable from `particular json file` (`same variable used in all json files`)

Comment: How about using database?

Comment: where json files should store?

Comment: it will be stored in `local`, and not php application.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can. 
As you mention, users should be logged in. So to each user can be attached specified attribute containing associated with him js file with data.

Or even simplier. JS file can be named as user login. So after login it can be loaded withot any troubles.